# Evaluating String in java Using ScriptEnging

Tags: java, scriptengine

Below is my code to take a somewhat simple user input of hello or mouse and search a String(I will later use this on much larger text files).

I use it to create a Java line of code that uses the contains method. After, I need to evaluate it. I found some help using the Script engine, but I keep getting this error: `Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "name" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1` The output that comes from the code that I want to evaluate is `name.contains("hello") || name.contains("mouse")`.

Any help would be great. Thanks

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ScriptException {


    String searchString = "name";
    String terms = "(hello) || (mouse)";

    String command = "";
    //multiple commands
    if(terms.contains("(") && terms.contains(")") && terms.contains("[") && terms.contains("]")){
        command = terms.replace(")","\")");
        command=command.replace("(", searchString + ".contains(\"");
        command = command.replace("[","(");
        command = command.replace("]",")");
    }
    //only ands/ only ors
    else {
        command = terms.replace("(", searchString + ".contains(\"");
        command = command.replace(")", "\")");
    }


    System.out.println(command);
    String name = "mousehellonamepe";


    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");

    Object result = engine.eval(command);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Interpreter i = new Interpreter();

    i.set("searchThis", searchString);
    i.set("answer", i.eval(command));
    Boolean answer2 = (Boolean) (i.get("answer"));
```

http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html#Calling_BeanShell_From_Your_Application

I used this to evaluate the command.
the link above provides all the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly ?

======= Update ======
First, String terms should be a list.

Make it:

```
ArrayList<String> searchTerms = new ArrayList();
```

Add as many words as you like to that list as follows:

```
// using add() to initialize values

    arr.add("Hello");
    arr.add("Mouse");
    arr.add("Bike");
    arr.add("House");

// use contains() to check if the element
        // 2 exits or not
        boolean mouseExists = arr.contains("Mouse");

if (ans)
        System.out.println("Our list contains the word mouse");
    else
        System.out.println("Our list does not contain the word mouse");
```

This should output this:

```
Our list contains the word mouse
```

Code should look like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ScriptException {

 ArrayList<String> searchTerms = new ArrayList();

arr.add("Hello");
        arr.add("Mouse");
        arr.add("Bike");
        arr.add("House");
boolean mouseExists = arr.contains("Mouse");

    if (ans)
            System.out.println("Our list contains the word mouse");
        else
            System.out.println("Our list does not contain the word mouse");

}
```

Comment: take the input as search terms, make it a piece of java code, and then use contains method to search a string (name)  to see if it has those search terms

Comment: For asking the OP for more details, use please the comments section.

Comment: I cannot use the comment section because I need to reach level 50 :)

Comment: Let me know if that helps ?

Comment: Thanks, but I needed to use && and || as many times as the user wants. also, the input needs to be from the user with the operations, so I cannot simply use a list. Thank you though!